# find who am I Riddle?

Tags: riddle

> Five hundred begins it, five hundred ends it, Five in the middle is seen
>
> First of all figures, the first of all letters, Take up their stations between
>
> Join all together, and then you will bring Before you the name of an eminent king.

```
Who am I?
```

Comment: I'm surprised this hasn't been asked before.  This is a fairly old/famous riddle.  It's even used in the puzzle game [Last Will](https://store.steampowered.com/app/453720/Last_Will/)

Comment: In the words of @David "It should've been "Together all join" instead of "Join all together" to make sense of "First of all figures" being before "the first of all letters"..."

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think you are

> David

Five hundred begins it, five hundred ends it, Five in the middle is seen

> In Roman numerals, 500 is **D** and 5 is **V**

First of all figures, the first of all letters, Take up their stations between

> First of all figures could be **I**, first of all letters would be **A**. These letters lie in between those found in the first hint.

Join all together, and then you will bring Before you the name of an eminent king.

> King David, second king of Israel and Judah.

Comment: first of all figures is rot13(ebzna ahzrenyf ntnva)